# Pivot and PanningBackgroundLayer

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have adding parallax background to Pivot control. I think need use PanningBackgroundLayer from Panorama.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you strictly required to use a Pivot? Panoramas can be styled to work like Pivots, if you modify your margins accordingly. That way you have the parallax effects of a Panorama in a layout that looks like a Pivot.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Panorama>
        <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="MY APPLICATION" Width="180" Margin="10,40,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>

        <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="PanoramaItem_1" Margin="0,0,0,32">
            <phone:LongListSelector>
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--Your Data Here-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="PanoramaItem_2" Margin="0,0,0,32">
            <phone:LongListSelector>
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--Your Data Here-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Comment: how can i combine headers from pivot and background from panorama in one single component?